# stop build up of clicks with jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little query, when I click on the image to toggle the navigation multiple times really fastly it builds up a que of clicks that go on by themselves, its really annoying and I can't figure out how to stop it as the jquery .stop isn't working.

here is the url

http://satbulsara.com/tests/

here is my code

```
$('img').toggle(function() { 
          $('ul').fadeIn("slow");
           },
           function() { 
           $('ul').fadeOut("slow"); 
           });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to clear the animation queue and stop the current effect before queuing a new one:

```
$('img').toggle(function() { 
    $('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
}, function() { 
    $('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic, for some reason when I added the stop before it was behaving funny, it must be the true that made it work perfectly.

Comment: @sat, yup, the first `true` clears the queue, and the second stops the current effect <strike>before it can retract</strike> immediately instead of letting it run its course.

Comment: Thanks Frederic your a star!!It makes so much sense when explained!!